# Julia debugging tool Gallium can't work on Julia v0.6

Tags: debugging, julia

When i try to debug my Julia program in Juno, it shows 'Gallium only works on Julia 0.5'. Can i use Gallium without transferring my Julia version to v0.5 ?

Comment: No you cannot. It's being upgraded, but it's not ready yet. You'll have to wait.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, I'm going to change my Julia version.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Do you know if there has been any updates on the debugger?

Comment: Keno created ASTInterpreter2.jl, an entire re-write of the system. It needs to be integrated with Juno. It's been slow coming since he's the one who worked on the Celeste project and got Julia running >1 petaflop, but now he's back to this.